# Win check in tic tac toe

Tags: python, python-3.x, tic-tac-toe

In this tic tac toe board I want to check for whether X or O has won. The formula I used was a for loop and I've only started doing it for the rows. It's not giving me the answer that I want. How else can I write this?

```
def win_check(board, mark):
    for mark in board:
        return (board[1:4] == board[4:7] == board[7:] == mark)
```

After I execute the above I check for whether X or O has won, like this:

```
>>> win_check(board, 'O')
False
```

It should be true because my board has rows 7,8,9 as Os.

Answer (score 2):

Your return function in win_check implies ALL the conditions must be concurrently met in order to win, ie board[1:4] == mark AND board[4:7] == mark AND board[7:] == mark. This would necessitate a board all covered in the same mark. You want OR conditions, so your code should read:

```
def win_check(board, mark):
    for mark in board:
        win = (all(mark == i for i in board[1:4]) or all(mark == i for i in board[4:7]) or all(mark == i for i in board[7:])
    return win
```

Also note I have moved your return statement OUT of your for loop. You do not want to return each time a loop occurs. Additionally, you do not test lists for same element in the way you have. Use the all method